# NTP clock drifting out of sync frequently. Offset too high

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I am having some problem with a local NTP server time synchronization. The clock drifts out of synchronization again and again.

I initially tried stopping the `ntpd` daemon. Then ran `ntpdate` to synchronize the time. and then started the `ntpd` daemon again. 
That resets the clock and the time is fine again but it simply drifts out of sync again.

Can someone help me identify the problem?

Here is the output of `ntpq -pn`.

[image: ntpq -pn]

Comment: Whats the output of `ntpq -pn`?

Comment: Updated question  with output of ntpq -pn

Comment: What hardware (CPU, motherboard) is the server running on? What VM technology, if applicable? What kernel (exact version)?

Comment: it seems to me that your system doesn't have an external time source

Comment: Replace RTC battery?